# Testing NativeProcess with FlexUnit

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flexunit4

I've set up a FlexUnit test on my Adobe Air project and want to test some functionality that uses NativeProcess. When I run the test it gives this error:

```
Error: Error #3219: The NativeProcess could not be started. 'Not supported in current profile.'
```

This is because the FlexUnitApplication-app.xml doesn't have this line enabling NativeProcess:

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
```

The problem is that FlexUnitApplication-app.xml gets auto generated each time it builds without that line.

I've been able to get it to work by running the test using "Run all tests" from the FlexUnit Results window and letting it fail. Then I add the line to FlexUnitApplication-app.xml in bin-debug and running the tests again. If anything in the project changes I need to repeat these steps so this isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it to your launch profile: click on the little arrow next to the bug icon and select Debug Configurations (or select the project properties > run/debug settings)
Choose the launch configuration you want to edit on the left of the new dialog. In the "main" tab of this config, the last option is "Profile", you can switch between "desktop" and "extendedDesktop" there.